# Jquery functions and appending elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i am new to jQuery. i am trying to create a function that reads from a xml. i have succeded in creating the function to reads from the xml file. Using the data in the xml, i am trying to creates a toggel menue.

here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
  {

    $.get('newsdata/news.xml', function(d){
    $('body').append('<div id="news" data-collapse="accordion"/>');

    $(d).find('event').each(function(){

        var $event = $(this); 
        var title = $event.attr("title");
        var description = $event.find('description').text();
        var imageurl = $event.attr('imageurl');

        var newcontent = '<h3>'+title+'</h3>';
        newcontent+= '<div>'+description+'</div>';

        $('#news').append($(newcontent)); //notworking
        $('.loadingPic').fadeOut(1400);
    });
      alert($('body').html());  
   });


});
</script>
```

every thing is working fine. however style sheets are not getting applied. when i take the html conted using `alert($('body').html())`and copy it in another html, its working. however not working when i append.

would be helpful if some one can guide me..
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello. You could try use `$("#news").html(newcontent)` instead

Comment: CSS rules will be applied to any dynamically appended elements automatically by the browser. Are you sure your CSS selectors (classes, ids, parents etc) match for the new elements?

Comment: `newcontent`(javascript variable) != `$(newcontent)` (wrapped with jQuery)

Comment: What is `$(d)`? where is it declared?

Comment: @Салман `$(d)` is declared in the $.get

Comment: I think it would help debugging, if you share your HTML, XML and JS as a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: No self closing div: `<div id="news" data-collapse="accordion"/>`

Comment: @Antony is correct: You have to append it like this: $('#news').append(newcontent)

Comment: @axel.michel & Anthony appending a HTML string or a jQuery object is perfectly valid. Check the API.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan I just mean from an ordinary point of view you shouldn't wrap it in a jQuery object when you can use the javascript variable directly.

Comment: @Anthony That's a fair point then. However claiming you 'have' to append it as a string (as axel did) is incorrect

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes, sorry, my fault, it's valid, the line was jus bit irritating.